# Assigning numpy array values based on complex indexing scheme

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I am attempting to populate a first [m x n] numpy array with values drawn from a second [m x n x f] array, where the index f is supplied by a third [m x n] array, and I’ve not yet been able to find a way to do this without expensive for loops.  Here is a simple representative example:

```
import numpy as np
import random

m, n, k  = 3, 2, 4
np.random.seed(1234)
a = np.random.randint(0,9,(m, n, k))
print(a)
b = np.random.randint(0,k,(m,n))
print(b)
c = np.zeros((m, n))
print(c)
```

I would now like to populate c with values from a as follows:

```
c[i,j] = a[i,j,b[i,j]]
```

In other words, for each position [i,j ] in c, draw the value from a at the same position [i,j] along the first two axes, and at a position along the third axis given by evaluating the array b at the [i,j] position.  In my example case (your random ints may vary?), the arrays are valued as follows:

```
a :
[[[3 6 5 4]
  [8 1 7 6]]
 [[8 0 5 0]
  [6 2 0 5]]
 [[2 6 3 7]
  [0 0 3 2]]]

b :
[[3 0]
 [1 3]
 [3 3]]
```

The desired result is:

```
c :
[[4 8]
 [0 5]
 [7 2]]
```

We arrive at this result as follows: start with i, j = 0,0.  Then, c[0,0] = [a[0,0,b[0,0]], and since b[0,0] is valued at 3, a is evaluated at a[0,0,3], which is 4.  Proceed to i, j = 0, 1.  Here c[0,1] = [a[0,1,b[0,1]], and since b[0,1] is valued at 0, a is evaluated at a[0,1,0], which is 8. And so on.  It is very clear to me how to do this with nested loops, but I am trying to avoid this since my actual arrays are much larger.  Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy indices broadcast to the shape of the output array:

```
c = a[np.arange(b.shape[0])[:, None], np.arange(b.shape[1]), b]
```

You can also use [`np.take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html) to avoid manually generating the index in the other axes, but here the index has to broadcast to the input array:

```
c = np.take_along_axis(a, b[..., None], -1)
```

Comment: Both very elegant solutions; thank you @Mad Physicist.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`np.unravel_index`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html) to create the indexes, index and then [`.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html#numpy.ndarray.reshape):

```
c = np.empty((m, n), dtype=np.int32)
ro, co = np.unravel_index(np.arange(n * m), (m, n))
c[:, :] = a[ro, co, b[ro, co]].reshape(3,2)
print(c)
```

**Output**

```
[[4 8]
 [0 5]
 [7 2]]
```

Comment: Many thanks @Dani Mesejo, this is exactly what I need.  I was not familiar with unravel_index; I'll need to study this to make sense of it, but it appears to be the right tool for the job.

Comment: This would be much simpler with `np.indices`

Comment: `b[ro, co]` is just `b`. No need to overcomplicate. Also, you can extract `c` without preallocating it.